# Header change on expand, but not on collapse

Tags: html, jquery

I have an expand/collapse box that when clicked the header changes from 'Click to show more information...' to 'Click to show less information...'

My issue is that it when the box collapses it won't change back to 'Click to show more information...' when clicked. Is there a way to edit the code I have to make this happen?

Here is the fiddle and code I have: http://jsfiddle.net/HFcvH/25/

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".content").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery(this).text("Click here for less information...");
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="heading">Click here for more info...&nbsp;</p>
<div class="content">
  <span style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(6, 78, 137);">
    <b>Documents Required</b>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow! Please make sure that you are aware about the [rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28679/the-rules-of-stack-overflow). If you find any of the below answers good enough, please upvote and accept it.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida, it doesn't make sense to put the code blocks in [a bulleted list](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7683858).

Comment: @gunr2171 The original post had a bulleted list. my bad then.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida, so it did, that I did not notice. Your edit must have got caught up with another edit at the same time. No worries then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your fiddle. I hide the div by default as you can see here:

```
$('#extra').hide();
$('#more').click(function() {
    var s = $(this);
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        s.html(s.text() == 'Less about us' ? 'More about us' : 'Less     about us');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".content").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
 var s = $(this);
jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
 s.html(s.text() == 'Click here for more info...' ? 'Click here for less information...' : 'Click here for more info...');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="heading">Click here for more info...</p>
 <div class="content">
      <span style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(6, 78, 137);">
          <b>Documents Required</b>
       </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The text that you have set for `<a>` is incorrect. Just change it to:

```
<a href="#" id="more">Less about us</a>
```

and, thats it!

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HFcvH/26/)

Answer (score 0):

I created a snipped a little bit more consistant :

http://jsfiddle.net/HFcvH/27/

i prefer to check if the element is visible rather than a text check, because it's more flexible

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    var s = $(this);
    $('#extra').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        s.html($(this).is(":visible") ? 'Less about us' : 'More about us');
    });
    return false;
}).trigger("click");
```